# Dimension of some ideal in the group ring Z/p[Z/p]

Tags: linear-algebra

Let I be the augmentation ideal of the group ring Z/p[Z/p] and I^n denotes the ideal generated by all possible products of n elements from I.
 Question: What is dimension of I^n as a vector subspace of Z/p[Z/p]? where n is a number in between 1 and (p-1) and p denotes a odd prime number.

Answer (score 1):

The group ring $\mathbb{F}_p[\mathbb{Z}/p]$ is $\mathbb{F}_p[T]/(T^p-1)$, or, putting $U=T-1$, $\mathbb{F}_p[U]/(U^p)$; the augmentation ideal $I$ is $(U)$, so $I^n=(U^n)$ has dimension $p-n$. I am not sure this is an adequate question for this site.

Comment: (The best way to deal with this sort of questions is *not* to answer them: flag them as needing migration to math.se, and probable add a comment to to that point)